# Verb for business trip

Tags: verbs

How can I complete this sentence? Which is the right verb?

I am out of the office because I'm...

-having a business trip in Venice.

-taking a business trip in Venice.

-.... .

Thank you.

Comment: I am ***on a business trip***..... https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/business-trip

Comment: travelling on business in Venice.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just make it a postmodifier: I'm in Venice [on business/for business]. "On business" sounds more natural and replaces "on a business trip".